# Fastest way to make a grid

Tags: extrude

Please tell me how to make a polygon of this type as in the grid in the example.
What is the fastest way to add points to the selected polygons to get a polygonal hole. Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right click > *Subdivide* your selection:

[image]

Then right click again > *LoopTools* (it's an addon that you need to enable) > *Circle*:

[image]

And <kbd>X</kbd> *(Delete) > Faces*:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

As a complementary answer you can work on one "unit"[image]

And use two array (one for the X axis, the other for the Y to create your grid

[image]